# Accessing class instance from a previous class

Tags: python

I have 2 files. The first file is:

```
import file1

Class MyTest:
    .
    .
     def Test(self):
          my_config = file1.Check_my_config()

     def add_something(self):
          do something
    .
    .
```

The file **file1** looks like this:

```
Class Check_my_config(object):

    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        do_something
        MyTest.self.add_something()
```

How do I access the previous class instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as an argument.

```
import file1

Class MyTest:
    .
    .
     def Test(self):
          # pass two required arguments e.g. a and b
          # (as defined by Check_my_config's __init__) and self
          my_config = file1.Check_my_config(a, b, self)

     def add_something(self):
          do something
    .
    .
```

---

```
Class Check_my_config(object):

    def __init__(self, var1, var2, mytest): # add a mytest parameter
        do_something
        mytest.add_something() # call a method bound to the passed mytest object
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I have a question, is it case sensitive? def __init__(self, var1, var2, MyTest): # add a mytest parameter
        do_something
        MyTest.add_something() # call a method bound to the passed mytest object

Comment: Yes, Python code is case-sensitive. `MyTest` is different from `mytest`, so follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to avoid confusion.